# PHP objects inside arrays (HOW TO: If array key is 0, return 0. Else if array key is 2, return 2. BASIC LOGIC)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

**What I'm trying to do:**
Get a list of names (if more than one) on a single string separated by a comma this way:

- `Britney Spears,` `Lady Gaga,` `Miley Cyrus`

**What's going on:**

- We are inside a loop.
- I'm trying to associate these `celebrities` to a post `ID`

So we have this unique `$id` for each loop.
More than one celebrity **name** can be attached to an **ID**.

**Query:**

```sql
$array = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT name
FROM celebrities
WHERE id = " . $id . "");
```

**PHP CODE:**

```php
if (is_array($array) && $array != null) {
    foreach($array as $single) {
        $array = $single->name . ',';
    }
}
else {
    $array = $array->name;
}
```

**Problem:**

With my code, I'm being limited to one celebrity per loop (even though the database shows that another celebrity should be present, as well).

I really just want to check if more than one celebrity `name` is present, then put them together inside a single string separated by a comma.

**Desired Output:**

Here's a simple outline of what I'm trying to accomplish:

- `array(0)` *(no celebrity)* = `// SHOW NOTHING`
- `array(1)` *(one celebrity name found)* = `echo $name`
- `array(2)` *(more than one celebrity)* = `foreach($names as $name)`

**Var_dump:**

I'd really just rather show you the complexity of the array structure:

```php
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1620 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1683 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1611 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(10)
"Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1614 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1690 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1598 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(4) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1722 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1706 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
[2] = >
    object(stdClass) #1668 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(10)
"Lady Gaga"
}
[3] = >
    object(stdClass) #1663 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(10)
"Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(4) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1615 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1708 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
[2] = >
    object(stdClass) #1723 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(10)
"Lady Gaga"
}
[3] = >
    object(stdClass) #1726 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(10)
"Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1598 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1663 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1722 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1734 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1598 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1750 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1751 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1716 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1776 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1795 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1647 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1784 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1776 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1611 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1676 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1781 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1715 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1813 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1826 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1828 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1717 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1765 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1769 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1848 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1690 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1660 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1821 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1717 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1766 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1836 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1765 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1826 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1843 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1854 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1820 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(5)
"Beyonce"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1814 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1847 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1866 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1820 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1814 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1847 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1875 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1821 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1786 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1880 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1746 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1815 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1817 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1811 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1874 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1819 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1798 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1820 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1802 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1853 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1741 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1867 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1820 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1688 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1919 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1889 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1923 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1927 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1811 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1904 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1910 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1889 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1927 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1904 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1843 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1860 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Miley Cyrus"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1889 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(5)
    "Beyonce"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1684 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1843 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1811 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(5)
    "Beyonce"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1900 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1904 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1926 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1915 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1829 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(5)
    "Beyonce"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1932 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(10)
"Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1889 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1952 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(5)
"Beyonce"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1915 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1829 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1932 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1892 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(3) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1899 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(5)
    "Beyonce"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1929 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(5)
"Beyonce"
}
[2] = >
    object(stdClass) #1805 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1886 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1829 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1802 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1932 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1941 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1836 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(5)
    "Beyonce"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1947 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1917 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1954 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1902 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(5)
    "Beyonce"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1836 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1970 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1842 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(5)
"Beyonce"
}
}
array(0) {}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1878 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(5)
    "Beyonce"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1802 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(5)
    "Beyonce"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1969 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1961 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(2) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1836 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1970 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(5)
"Beyonce"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1902 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1979 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1860 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(1) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1946 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(6)
    "Madonna"
}
}
array(3) {
    [0] = >
        object(stdClass) #1926 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
        string(10)
    "Lady Gaga"
}
[1] = >
    object(stdClass) #1848 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(5)
"Beyonce"
}
[2] = >
    object(stdClass) #1912 (1) {
    ["name"]= >
    string(6)
"Madonna"
}
}
array(0) {}
```

I believe I am getting confused for no reason, but I am stuck.

Comment: Watch out for SQL Injection.  Is the query going to return an array if there are multiple results?

Comment: i didnt understand exactly but php (implode) or mysql (group concat) will help you.

Comment: @MattWhipple : Yes, it would return arrays (some null). It's not the query that is the problem though, I am trying to get the results in a string by going through a foreach, but I am only able to return one result each time, when there should be more. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
foreach($array as $single) {
    $array = $single->name . ',';
}
```

`$array` is only an array the first time the loop is executed as inside the loop your assigning it a new value.

Try this instead:

```
$names = array();
foreach ($array as $single) {
    $names[] = $single->name;
}
echo implode(', ', $names);
```

Comment: Thank you @Dale, smart guy you are. I'm surprised you understood my jibberish at all. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with Dale, because in your example, you will always get one name(the last one from, for example, database), so you should put it in a different array when looping